# How to handle "Logcat: E/TextView initAddtionalStyle default"?

Tags: android, logcat

I'm writing an android app(indeed) and got an issue, which is not killing my software, but if I see something in my logcat i want to understand it, too.

However I've got a layout which will be displayed on game over. It is initialized onCreate(). Additional i have a layout for pause.
The Pause layout doesn't show the message but the gameoverView I load right after does.

I checked both xml files and there is nothing i can find, which would make the difference.

I searched for the "E/TextView" but there is nothing helpful.

Thanks and may the potato be with you!

```
<com.***.CustomEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/changeBox"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="@string/changeText"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        style="@style/myEditBox"/>
```

Comment: On one page this message where caused by "MultiLine". Without it still uses multiple lines and not a message "E/TextView..."

Comment: The other message where caused by a EditText(!) ("E/TextView..."). I made it now a custom one but still.... even when i only let the id in the declaration i've got the message

Comment: It seems, that my phone is causing the issue.

Comment: well, i sent a mail to my mobile producer and they told me that the mail got forwared to their developer team (they might going to read this entry as well =) )... hope it is just the overlay on the OS ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to Huawei Support and got a really awkward answer.

They think they don't have to care about it.
I don't understand why, but it seems that they are serious about it.

So, I guess it is their bug and they don't care about it.

Closed